# Setting an object array with in an ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have the following MediaObject object that contains :

- a Media object
- an array
- and a function getMedia()

Within my getMedia function I make an ajax call and on success I want to be able to
 create a Media object and push that object into my array.  However, I am unable to reference my array for some reason , how should I reference it ?

I've tried both : MediaObject.arrayList.push(mediaItem) and this.arrayList.push(mediaItem); 
Neither work.

```
    function  MediaObject(){

            function Media(){
              this.id = "";
            }

            this.arrayList = [];

            AmebaObject.prototype.getMedia = function(){
              $.ajax({
                        url: this.rooturl+ this.loginurl,
                        type: 'GET',
                        headers: myheaders,
                        dataType: 'xml',
                        success: function (xml) {    
                             this.xml = xml;
                            $(xml).find("media").each(function(){
                               var mediaItem = new Media();
                               mediaItem.id = $(this).find('id').text();
                               MediaObject.arrayList.push(mediaItem);
                            });

                        },
                        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            console.log("Status code : " + xhr.status);
                            console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);
                        }
                    });
            }

}
```

---

**Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined**

Comment: `this` isn't what you think it is. You should add `context: this` to your ajax request to remedy that. (this will not solve your problem though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the arrayList to be part of the MediaObject function, then write

```
MediaObject.arrayList = [];
```

If you want to reference arrayList as a member of a MediaObject, then you need to change how you reference it in the success function.

Comment: why doesn't this.arrayList suffice?

Comment: @Fabii because `this` isn't `MediaObject` in the success callback. See my comment on your question.

Comment: I meant when declaring the array, can I not use  this.arrayList to declare arrayList as a property of MediaObject ?

Comment: Yes, that's how it's done.  It's getting to the instance later that's the problem because of how Javascript handles 'this' references in functions.  The 'this' in getMedia() isn't necessarily referencing the MediaObject.  You're almost better using var instead of this in order to pull it off.

Answer (score 1):

I might be getting it wrong, but to me, your `MediaObject` is a constructor, while the way you access `MediaObject.arrayList` suggests static property. Which is a bit confusing.

As user1329482 suggested, you can use arrayList statically, but then you probably should define it outside of the constructor (otherwise every new instance will reset it).

If, however, you want to use it as an instance property, using `this` is your only option. In order to use `this` inside of callback’s scope you have to either define some local variable (commonly `var that = this`) and access it that way, or `bind()` your callback.